# No effect: CATextLayer wrapped

Tags: ios, calayer, ios8.3, catextlayer

I have critical issue.

I develop iOS Application.
I tried to use this app on iOS 8.3, CATextLayer doesn't work as before.

I thought "wrapped" property doesn't work.
Because CATextLayer has correct height and width.
But just text is not wrapped.

If text is multiple lines, only end of line has this issue.

Official reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catextlayer/1515302-wrapped

Answer (score 0):

When computing the height for your text layer, use `ceil(h + 1)`, where `h` is the height returned by the `boundingRectWithSize` method. Basically, `boundingRectWithSize` is broken, returning insufficient vertical space. `CATextLayer` then decides that since it can't fit in the final line, it's better to send the string off the right edge...

Confusing API description is given here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

There is [LabelKit](https://github.com/edudnyk/LabelKit) project that supports multiline text animation on the basis of `UILabel`, keeping layout constraints content sizing and animating much more than `CATextLayer` was capable of.